# compiling corba .idl file error

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments, corba, idl

[Eclipse IDL compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814074/eclipse-idl-compilation)

So im in the directory of the .idl file and I want to compile the gridDemo file, So I type idlj gridDemo.idl and I get the error that idlj is not a recognized as an internal or external command

What am I doing wrong ?

Yes Im running windows

I have installed the java sdk,

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin

Is this the path I put into the system variable path?

SOLVED I was using the wrong file. it should have been the jdk not jre folder.

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the `PATH` environmental variable to include the location of the `idlj.exe` executable

```
%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
```

Comment: Im very to new to all this and not sure what exactly you are telling me to do, could you explain more ?

Answer (score 4):

Please check the file `idlj.exe` under `JDK directory`(found it in jdk 1.4 and later),

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin\` and ,

add it to path under environment variables :

`%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin\`